# What would have happened if Edward hadn't stopped?

Tags: twilight

In *Twilight*, when Edward was sucking the venom out of Bella he was addicted to it and almost couldn't stop.

He got all the venom out, so what would happen if he had sucked all her blood? Would she have died or would she become a vampire?

Comment: I think vampire lore varies. I believe in some cases it is like a contagion and in other cases it is based on whether the vampire actually exchanges blood and perhaps the vampire needs to completely drain the victim or some other aspect of the procedure affects whether the victim turns. It may also be choice the vampire makes, deciding whether a victim will become a vampire and maybe no blood of the vampire needs to be provided. Bottom line, some authors have had humans NOT become vampires simply because they had been bitten -- there might be further requirements.

Comment: @releseabe - OP has restricted this specifically to the lore of one single fictional universe, that of the Twilight books (and presumably films).

Comment: *"So… if the venom is left to spread…" I murmured.

"It takes a few days for the transformation to be complete, depending on how much venom is in the bloodstream, how close the venom enters to the heart. As long as the heart keeps beating, the poison spreads, healing, changing the body as it moves through it. Eventually the heart stops, and the conversion is finished. But all that time, every minute of it, a victim would be wishing for death."*

Comment: @Valorum I see -- I had thought she was giving just an example. But even so, it is important that people know about how vampirism spreads lest it happen again.

Answer (score 1):

According to *[The Twilight Saga: The Official Illustrated Guide](https://www.goodreads.com/nl/book/show/3609763)*, draining a human of their blood will result in their immediate death, irregardless of whether they've already been bitten or have poison in their body.

> *The transformation is difficult from the vampire perspective as well. Even mature vampires have trouble resisting flowing human blood. The scent affects them as it does sharks; they can go into a feeding frenzy. For this reason, vampires tend to not hunt in packs. During the irrational frenzy, members of a coven are likely to turn on one another in competition for the blood. The taste of human blood makes it even harder for the vampire to resist. It is nearly impossible for a vampire to not drain the human — **thus killing him or her** — once the vampire has tasted blood. Only vampires with a great deal of self-control are able to remain focused enough to bite a human and then let him live long enough for the venom to effect the change.*